# FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.url returns value delayed

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

```
protected function onApplicationCreationComplete( event : FlexEvent ) : void
{
   var xURL : String = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.url;
   // ...
   // next fragment of code
}
```

*`next fragment of code`* will be executed before `xURL` receive the application URL.

How to capture when the `FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.url` is ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This property is set in Application's initialize function.
You can try to override it and read url property after call to super.initialize()